# The CPP folder is empty, and the native method not working

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm trying to use a native method writing in c++, in my android application, I've followed this steps :

1 - I've created **JNI** folder, and copied the **cpp** file to it.

[image]

2 - I've created **CMakeLists.txt** file in : **app\CMakeLists.txt**

[image]

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC src/main/jni/*.cpp src/main/cpp/*.c)
add_library( kitdemo-lib SHARED ${SRC} )

find_library( log-lib log )

target_link_libraries( kitdemo-lib ${log-lib} )
```

3 - I've modified the `Gradle` file :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.abc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

4 - I've added the NDK location :

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Sdk
ndk.dir=D\:\\Sdk\\ndk\\21.4.7075529
```

But still, the CPP looks empty, and the app crash when I call the native method

[image]

Comment: Maybe include the stack trace?

Comment: What does the build log say? Also, I'm not sure why you expect the cpp-directory to be auto-populated(?). That's typically where you place your C and C++ _source code_. Note that in your CMakeLists.txt you have referenced the jni directory for one set of source files, and the cpp directory for another.

Comment: What I have done as a sanity check in cases like this is to create an absolutely new Android project with C++ support. Then I compare the two directory structures, gradle files, etc. to make sure that I didn't forget something. This happens more often than I care to admit...